# Create separate shortcut for 1 and 2 screen VM

Tags: virtualbox, display

I have a VM that I sometimes want to use on one screen, and other times want to use two screens. I know I can hop into the display settings for the VM and change it, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way. Is it possible to create two shortcuts for 1 VM, each with different display settings?

- Host OS: Windows 10
- VM: Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop

Comment: Not sure if this will work or not, but could you have a snapshot of one with the 1 screen setting and another with the 2 screen setting? Might have to clone it and have 2 separate VM instances